# A Visual Studio 2010 Bug?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio

I think I found a bug in VS2010 (C / C++), but it seems so obvious, I cannot believe it.
(in the vein of [Select isn't Broken](http://pragmatictips.com/26)).

Please let me know if this is a bug, or if I'm missing something:

```
int main(void)
{
    int x;  // Declare a variable x;

    for(int i=0, x = 10; i<5; ++i) // Initialize X to 10.  No way around this.
    {
        printf("i is %d\n", i);
    }

    if (x == 10) // warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'x' used    
    {
        printf("x is ten\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a bug. But not in your compiler.

Comment: I'm surprised by the down-votes.  I freely acknowledged that it likely wasn't a real compiler bug, and asked what I'm missing.

Comment: But you could have tested this by trying it in a different compiler. I'd also make your title more about your code and less about the apparent plausible bug in VS.

Comment: People seem a bit harsh on this site.  Methinks it's from the strict rule following due to excessive C++ programming.

Comment: It compiles without warnings in g++ and gcc (std=c99).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
int i=0, x = 10;
```

You just declared a second `x` variable scoped to the `for` loop.

The outer `x` variable is not affected.

Comment: You're right... I was missing something simple!
(bad news: despite my simple repro-case above, I found this in important production code....)

Comment: @abelenky: And that's why you should treat warnings as errors.

Comment: Long story short:  I *always* treat warnings as errors.  My new employer has been suppressing warnings.  I'm in the process of going back over these old suppressed warnings and investigating and fixing them.

Answer (score 0):

To test this you should try compiling the code in a different compiler.  Using gcc (without the `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic` flags):

```
$ gcc a.c
a.c: In function ‘main’:
a.c:7: error: redeclaration of ‘x’ with no linkage
a.c:5: error: previous declaration of ‘x’ was here
a.c:7: error: ‘for’ loop initial declaration used outside C99 mode
a.c:9: warning: too few arguments for format
a.c:9: warning: too few arguments for format
```

As stated, the issue is you declared a different variable with tighter scope in the for loop.